# Update arbitrary member with only non null values

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have two classes with no inheritance relationship (well, excepting being Object):

```
class A
{
  Member1 m1;
  Member2 m2;
}

class B
{
  Member1 m3;
  Member2 m4;
}
```

Each member of a class is paierd with a member of the same arbitrary type in the other class, it might or might not have the same name, it can be null.
I would like to do something like this:

```
 if (b.m3 != null) a.m1 = b.m3;
```

just to update values that are not null, where `a` is an instance of class `A` and `b` is an instance of class `B`.
The number of members to update might grow with time, I'd like some more general and elegant way to do the update, something to be used like this:

```
a.Update(d => d.m1, b.m3)
```

I have tried with an extension method:

```
public static void Update<TSource, TKey>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, TKey> key, TKey newValue)
 where TSource : A
{
 if (newValue != null)
 {
  key(source) = newValue;
 }
}
```

but there is clearly something wrong because I get an exception saying that the left-hand side of the the equality `key(source)` must be a variable.
Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders, I will have a look at AutoMapper, it already was in my extremely long to-learn list, it's about time to do it for real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because a `Func` is literally a function that returns a value.  When called you have to assign that value to a variable, thus the error message you are getting.  Instead of a `Func` you could use an `Action` and pass both the source and the key to it.

```
public static void Update<TSource, TKey>(
    this TSource source, 
    Action<TSource, TKey> action, 
    TKey newValue)
 where TSource : A
{
     if (newValue != null)
     {
        action(source, newValue);
     }
}
```

Then call it like this.

```
a.Update((myA, val) => myA.m1 = val, b.m3);
```

But really it would be simpler to just do the following

```
a.m1 = b.m3 ?? a.m1;
```

That will assign `b.m3` to `a.m1` if it is not `null`.  Otherwise it just assigns `a.m1` to itself.

Although for this specific case you should look into mapping libraries that can handle this type of thing for you.

Comment: Thank you, your code works fine, I was missing the Action vs Func bit. Your suggestion for semplicity is of course right, but in the real application I need to do more checks than I have explained in the question, but I can handle them myself with this extension method running. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
Member1 m1;
public Setm1(Member1 in)
{
  if (in != null) m1 = in;
}
```

Then your code is very simple:

```
a.Setm1(b.m3);
```

Or you could use the accessor (with the same code) and you would have

```
public Member1 Setm1
{
   set {  if (value != null) m1 = value;
}

a.Setm1 = b.m3;
```

Comment: Your code does the right thing, but I'd need to create a property or method for each member, which isn't optimal when the number of members of the class can vary. Thanks for your answer.